# Magento 2: What is the difference between the row_id and entity_id in the %_entity tables?

Tags: magento2, database, eav

In Magento 1, there wasn't a column called `row_id` in the entity tables, you just had the `entity_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type ID',
  `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attriute Set ID',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Parent Category ID',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Update Time',
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tree Path',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Position',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tree Level',
  `children_count` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Child Count',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_LEVEL` (`level`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_PATH_ENTITY_ID` (`path`,`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=943 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Category Table'
```

But Magento 2 introduces a concept of `row_id` which becomes the primary key for an entity, it seems to have something to do with versioning from the comment:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity` (
  `row_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Version Id',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `created_in` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Update Id',
  `updated_in` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Next Update Id',
  `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attriute Set ID',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Parent Category ID',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Creation Time',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Update Time',
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tree Path',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Position',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tree Level',
  `children_count` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Child Count',
  PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_LEVEL` (`level`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_CREATED_IN` (`created_in`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_UPDATED_IN` (`updated_in`),
  KEY `CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID_SEQUENCE_CAT_CTGR_SEQUENCE_VAL` (`entity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID_SEQUENCE_CAT_CTGR_SEQUENCE_VAL` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `sequence_catalog_category` (`sequence_value`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=956 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Category Table'
```

This is causing me some uncertainty when wanting to join eav fields as now the types refer to the `row_id` instead of the `entity_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `row_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Version Id',
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` (`row_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID` (`row_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CAT_CTGR_ENTT_VCHR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `CAT_CTGR_ENTT_VCHR_ROW_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ROW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`row_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`row_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=266383 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Category Varchar Attribute Backend Table'
```

Currently in the entity table `row_id` and `entity_id` are the same:

```
select row_id, entity_id from catalog_category_entity limit 3;        
+--------+-----------+
| row_id | entity_id |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |         1 |
|      2 |         2 |
|      3 |         3 |
+--------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am unsure the circumstances where `row_id` will change and what impact this will have on the Magento system, I have looked for documentation on this feature but cannot find any.

I want to know the following:

- Can the same entity have multiple `row_id`s?

  - If so how is the active entity defined?
  - If not what is the mechanism Magento uses to update these.
- <strike>What is the core use of this feature and is there any documentation?</strike>

  - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/staging/Staging.html

Comment: I think you answered your own question. One entity can have multiple rows with the same value for entity_id and a different value for row_id. Depending on the 'version' of an entity a different row_id will be selected. So each version will have its own row_id.

Comment: I think this `row_id` is only in EE. If you install fresh Magento CE, you won't see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I have found on this one, `row_id` is the identifier for the row, while `entity_id` is the actual entity.

There are situations where a Scheduled Update is set to run for a fixed period and in this case a whole new row is created to associate with it's variant `eav_attribute`(s) and it can retain the same `entity_id` while being issued a new `row_id` Then the `row_id` is changed to the new temporary entity and then back to the original once the schedule completes.

There may be other use cases where they make use of this, this was one which I witnessed and illuminates how it can be used.

Comment: Not sure in which situation the entity_id and row_id are different ?

Answer (score 1):

The `entity_id` is used in the Magento 2 EE Version only. It is used as an Index defined in `catalog_category_entity` pointing to `sequence_catalog_category`.

The sequence tables, in general, are used for the database splitting feature.

Answer (score -3):

I would say that the purpose is to keep compatibility with Magento 1. When you need to migrate data from m1 to m2 you will need that relationship.