# Magento 2 : row id and entity id not same in catalog_product_entity table

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, query

Executed query -

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(parent_id SEPARATOR ',') AS parent_id
FROM catalog_product_super_link AS super_link
WHERE super_link.product_id = 914066
```

The issue is there are records where "row id" & "entity id" is different.
Any thoughts what can be the reason ?

[image]

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/216065/36463

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but its still unclear if both should be same or different

Comment: In which situation the entity_id and row_id are different ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **row_id** only available in the enterprise edition(Adobe Commerce).There is no rule for **row_id** and **entity_id** should be the same or not the same. Most entries have the same row_id and entity_id and some have different enity_id and row_id. So it is not a problem.

[Magento 2: What is the difference between the row_id and entity_id in the %_entity tables?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/139081/36463)

If you are developing a custom extension in Magento EE, keep this in mind, eav tables values are mapped with **row_id** not entity_id.

Please check this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/279579/36463) for the difference between row_id and entity_id. It is mainly used for content staging.

> **Example:** You want to change a product name for a month. You can schedule that change using the content staging by specifying a
> different product name for the date range needed. Behind the scenes,
> Magento will utilize that row_id (among other meta data to support
> this feature) to store the scheduled change. If a customer visits the
> site during the time the product name was scheduled to be changed,
> Magento will end up loading the row_id corresponding to the how the
> product was scheduled to "look" at that point in time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please also add in which situation the
 enity_id and row_id are different ?

Comment: Not sure in which situation the entity_id and row_id are different ?

Comment: @devhs Please check the example again, we can understand new row_id will be added when we added schedule(content staging), here is the point, row_id and entity_id is differing.